# Where can I ask about payment processors for use in a website?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask about payment processors for use in a website. The one I found on Stack Overflow was closed because it's off-topic. None of the others automatically lend themselves to this question. Any ideas?

Comment: SO is more about problem solving not crowd sourcing opinions on what software, I honestly am not sure it belongs on any of the SE sites. I could see Webmasters maybe. But it may be best to look up some solutions and just do a comparison yourself. If you're having problems implementing a payment processor and have made a legit attempt and failed then by all means SE is the place to be.

Comment: You may also want to crowd source some forums for opinions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it a [shopping question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) or [product comparison?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) Shopping and comparison questions are off-topic throughout the Stack Exchange network.

If it's not a shopping question, you can try [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).  [Read their FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) first, before posting.

Comment: Well I'm looking for a specific solution - I don't know what my options are, but I guess the question would border pretty close to a product comparison if more than once solution fitted the bill.

Comment: Having just looked at Webmasters I think its OK :) thanks